# Flask, HTMX barcode generation

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, barcode, htmx

I have a mongodb data collection called "tickets". I have code (below) that find all of the session users tickets (if any) and returns them to a htmx get request. I want to generate a barcode for each ticket using the default "_id" from each of the users tickets, and also return that. Current code and template:

Ticket template:

```html
{% for ticket in tickets %}
  <div class="ticket" id="ticket">
    <h1>Ticket</h1>
    <p>This is a ticket of the type: {{ ticket.type }}</p>
    <p>It is owned by {{ ticket.username }}</p>
    <p>Ticket ID = {{ticket._id}}</p>                
  </div>   
{% endfor %}
```

Userpage:

```html
        <h1>
            Tickets:
        </h1>
        <div id="userTickets" hx-get="/get_tickets" hx-trigger="load"></div>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("htmx:afterRequest", function(event) {
              // Check if the request was for the userTicketsDiv
              if (event.detail.elt.id === "userTickets") {
                // Parse the JSON response from the backend
                var responseData = JSON.parse(event.detail.response);
                
                // Assuming your backend returns an array of ticket objects
                // you can create a simple list to display the tickets.
                var ticketsList = "<ul>";
                responseData.forEach(function(ticket) {
                  ticketsList += "<li>" + ticket.name + " - " + ticket.description + "</li>";
                });
                ticketsList += "</ul>";
          
                // Update the content of the userTicketsDiv
                document.getElementById("userTickets").innerHTML = ticketsList;
              }
            });
          </script>
```

```py
@app.route("/get_tickets", methods=["GET"])
def get_tickets():
    # Get the username from the session
    username = session.get("username")
    if not username:
        return jsonify({"error": "Username parameter is missing."}), 400

    # Query the 'tickets' collection for the user's tickets
    user_tickets = list(mongo.db.tickets.find({"username": username}))

    # Convert ObjectId instances to string representation
    for ticket in user_tickets:
        ticket["_id"] = str(ticket["_id"])

    # Check if the user has any tickets
    if not user_tickets:
        return jsonify({"message": "No tickets found for this user."}), 404

    # Render the tickets.html template with the user_tickets data
    return render_template("ticket.html", tickets=user_tickets)
```

I tried using libraries such as JsBarcode and python-barcode but none of them returned a barcode or an error.